# Unable to locate element with id, class_name and xpath using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to click this button:

[image: picture of element i need info on]

I have tried the following:

```
sumbitbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text() = 'mt8 mb8']")
```

I decided to insted abandon this method and go for a nuther as it lead to a lot of other problums latter down the line

Comment: `mt8 mb8` is not the text of that element; it is the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `<div>` tags aren't clickable. Additionally `mt8 mb8` are the classanmes, not the text.

---

### Solution

As per the HTML:

[image: snapshot]

to click on the `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.inputButton.main_submit[value='Submit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputButton.main_submit' and @value='Submit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You will want something like:

```
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "inputButton.main_submit")))
button.click()
```

As you did not confirm the URL, I cannot test it, but it should work.

Also, do not forget to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```